# Error sending mail with Google API - "'raw' RFC822 payload message string or uploading message via /upload/* URL required"

Tags: python-3.x, gmail-api, google-api-python-client

I am trying to send a message via the Google API in python, and am trying to run an example taken almost directly from the [Google example page](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/sending).

```
def CreateMessage(sender, to, subject, message_text):
    message = MIMEText(message_text)
    message['to'] = to
    message['from'] = sender
    message['subject'] = subject
    return {'raw': base64.urlsafe_b64encode(message.as_string().replace('message','resource').encode('ascii'))}
```

But when I try to send it

```
    message = CreateMessage(sender, to, subject, message_text)
    message = service.users().messages().send(body=list(message),userId='me').execute()
```

I get the error : "'raw' RFC822 payload message string or uploading message via /upload/* URL required"

From other posts it seems like Google is expecting an attachment. Is there something wrong with the MIMEText making it expect one, and if so, how do I fix it?

Comment: How big is the message?

Comment: Even if I leave the string empty, or a couple of dozen lines, I still get the error.

Comment: Check this SO question [Failed sending mail through google api with javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30590988/failed-sending-mail-through-google-api-with-javascript) and [How to `insert` a `full` format message using the Gmail API?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26487630/how-to-insert-a-full-format-message-using-the-gmail-api) if it can help you.

Comment: I was getting your error as well and managed to succeed with this answer

Answer (score 7):

I was able to get the [example](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/sending#sending_messages) working by removing the changing `create_message` to:

```
create_message = {
        'raw': encoded_message
    }
```

Comment: Although this is mentioned in document - create_message={'message':{'raw':encoded_message}}. However replacing it with create_message={'raw':encoded_message} does work in my case.

Answer (score 3):

`list(message)` is not necessary and is giving the API a body of:

```
[{"raw": "b64 content..."}]
```

just do:

```
...messages().send(body=message, userId='me'...
```

Comment: I had not been using 'list' and received the same error message.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following :

```
msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
msg['Subject'] = subject
msg['From'] = sender
msg['To'] = to
msg.attach(MIMEText(message_text, 'plain'))
return {'raw': base64.urlsafe_b64encode(msg.as_string().encode()).decode()}
```